# PHP cookie proper way to redirect?

Tags: php, html, cookies, header

so I made a simple user log in website, and I want to set a cookie so that when they come back to the website, it will take them to the members area and not the main page, kind of like a "remember me" function that redirects users to a members area if a cookie is set.

Problem I am facing: The php code right before the html code does not redirect to the member.php page even though the cookie is set!

Note: I'm just using parts of the code, and not the entire code/ other files to simplify the question.

here's my code:

main.php    (this is the main page, and also where the log-in form is, but log in form is not shown)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<?php 
     //Checks if there is a login cookie
     if(isset($_COOKIE["blablabla"]))  //if cookie is set
     {  
        header("Location: www.website.com/member.php"); //redirect to member.php
     }
    else
    {
        //otherwise, redirect to nocookiefound.php
        header("Location: www.website.com/nocookiefound.php"); 
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo "Welcome " . $_COOKIE["blablabla"] . "!<br />";
            //I ran a echo test to see if cookie is still there, and it is.
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

So my question is, can my redirect work the way it is?

I must be doing something wrong because it's not redirecting to member.php even though the cookie echos the correct value.

So, if i was originally in the members.php page after I logged in, then go back to main.php, it SHOULD redirect me to members.php, but it doesn't, it just stays at main.php. Anyone know what's going on? I would appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as what @Dogbert says, your redirection is invalid. Try:

```
header("Location: http://www.website.com/member.php");
```

Comment: Yes, and maybe add the "CODE" of redirect should be better.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP code should be the first thing on the page, as you're sending a redirect "Header". Move it to before the Doctype declaration.

Comment: not to mention the missing "exit" the rest of the php code is still going to run

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, put an exit(); after the header lines. It's possible to write a script that ignores headers, hence running the other code inadvertently.

People often use headers to protect admin areas without realising that.